# Is it OK for a factory method to return null?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, factory-method

I'm wondering about best practice here. Is it good practice for a factory method to return null if it can't create anything? Here's an example:

```
ICommand command = CommandFactory.CreateCommand(args);
if (command != null)
    command.Execute();
else
    // do something else if there is no command
```

An alternative would be to return a `NullCommand` or something, I guess, but what is best practice?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think it's potentially reasonable for a factory method to return null in some situations, but *not* if it's a method called `CreateCommand`. If it were `GetCommand` or `FetchCommand`, that might be okay... but a `Create` method should throw an exception on failure, I would suggest.

Whether you *really* want it to return `null` in this situation depends on the bigger picture, of course. (Is there a reasonable null object implementation you could return instead, for example?)

Comment: Agree with @Jon Skeet. Create implies constructor, and you don't expect a null from one of them, so it's unlikely you would check to see if that was what it did.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: On the other side, you wouldn't expect an Exception from a constructor either.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Why not? I would *absolutely* expect an exception from constructors in certain situations - `FileStream` being a classic example... or anything with parameters which may be invalid in any form, e.g. giving a null reference to something expecting a non-null reference.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, in _certain_ situations, but it's a fluent passage(what's the correct english term?). This is one of the cases where i'm missing java's `throws` keyword to ensure that it's handled by the caller.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Even in Java you wouldn't use it for things like obviously-invalid parameters. Basically I don't regard a constructor throwing an exception as being particularly different from a method throwing an exception, except that you need to be more careful if you've allocated any unmanaged resources (as the caller won't be able to dispose of the newly constructed object).

Comment: @TimSchmelter It should be rare, and I'd try to avoid it e.g. Initialise method for resources, but throwing an exception is way better than the alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

Returning `null` in this case will make your method harder to use; clients have to be aware of an implicit failure condition. Instead, throw an exception, and you can also provide a separate method for clients to test for this condition:

```
if (CommandFactory.CanCreate(args)) {
  ICommand command = CommandFactory.Create(args);
  command.Execute();
}
```

Or make the factory instantiatable; which would be better if you need to pre-process `args`:

```
CommandFactory factory = new CommandFactory(args);
if (factory.IsValid()) {
  ICommand command = factory.Create();
  command.Execute();
}
```

The interface of the factory now makes it clear and explicit that creation might fail, but it still requires the client to use the checking method. Another option is this:

```
ICommand command;
if (CommandFactory.TryCreate(args, out command)) {
  // creation succeeded ...
}
```

Comment: _"will possibly fail if they don't check for null"_ Since C# does not support checked exceptions(unlike java), clients might also fail if they don't handle that exception, so that's not a strong argument(imho).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I revised my wording on that phrase.... Hope my view is clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jon Skeet. `CreateCommand` clearly implies construction.

If you won't throw an `Exception`, then in that scenario I would personally go with the `NullCommand` implementation, to avoid conditional statements in all consumers and possible `NullReferenceException` errors.

Answer (score 0):

It only makes sense to return Null if there's a reason why you would *want* the user to have to check for null every time he calls Create. Normally you'd consider the following a perfectly valid use pattern:

```
var obj = MyFactory.CreateThing();
obj.DoSomething();
```

But what you're proposing is to force the following usage pattern:

```
var obj = MyFactory.CreateThing();
if (obj == Null) {
    // Handle null condition
} else {
    obj.DoSomething();
}
```

Normally the *Null* scenario would mean some sort of failure, in which case an Exception would probably make the most sense. But ultimately you're the music maker here and have to decide what is sensible in the world you're building.