# Abstract factory bad design?

Tags: abstract-factory

I have car factories that build cars of different sizes. 
I have 2 factories: USA and Thailand that make car sizes Big, Middle, and Little. 
But I have a problem: the Thailand factory does not make big cars.

Code:

```
public enum CarSize { Big, Middle, Little,}

public interface ICarFactory {
    ICar CreateCar(CarSize carSize);
}

public class USACarFactory : ICarFactory {
    public ICar CreateCar(CarSize carSize) {
        ICar car = null;
        switch (carSize) {
            case CarSize.Little:
                car = new USALittleCar();
                break;
            case CarSize.Middle:
                car = new USAMiddleCar();
                break;
            case CarSize.Big:
                car = new USABigCar();
                break;
        }
        return car;
    }
}

public class ThailandCarFactory : ICarFactory {
    public ICar CreateCar(CarSize carSize){
        ICar car = null;
        switch (carSize) {
            case CarSize.Little:
                car = new ThailandLittleCar();
                break;
            case CarSize.Middle:
                car = new ThailandMiddleCar();
                break;
            case CarSize.Big:
                //no big cars in Thailand!!!!
                break;
        }
        return car;
    }
}

public interface ICar { }

public class USABigCar : ICar { }
public class USAMiddleCar : ICar { }
public class USALittleCar : ICar { }

public class ThailandMiddleCar : ICar { }
public class ThailandLittleCar : ICar { }
```

What should I do?
Is my Abstract Factory poorly designed?

Comment: Why did you do this `case CarSize.Big: no big cars in Thailand!!!! break;`? You said that: But, i have a problem: in Thailand factory does not make a big cars!!!, but then you don't allow Thailand's factory to make big cars? I don't understand your point here. Please clarify.

Comment: i mean, if i ask from Thailand factory to do big car, i will get null. Comments i use for better visibility.

Comment: that's because you wrote the code so thailand factory doesn't make big cars...

Comment: illuminaty - if was Thailand making big cars, it was perfect! but it does not!
I can change abstraction to factory by country name, not by size:
public interface ICarFactory
{
    ICar CreateCar(Country countryName);
}
and implement MiddleCarFactory, LittleCarFactory, but what about implementing BigCarFactory? Does i need ignore it and not to implement? So, client need to remember, that Little and Middle cars he can make by factory and Big cars he need to create by calling:
ICar car6 = new USABigCar(); ????
There some bad abstraction, but i didn'k know where...

Comment: now i read, that i need throw exception, if there no big car in thailand:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124562/is-it-ok-for-a-factory-method-to-return-null

does it normal practise to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zzfima, picking up the idea from COM, how about querying the interface and find out it if supports creating car of a specified size and invoke suitably? The code definitely realizes the abstract factory pattern.

Comment: Thanks
But (in my implementation) it returns null, that equal to "not supports creating car of a specified size". Maybe i wrong, but idea from COM enlarge amount of code, but Thailand continue make only Little and middle cars. Once again, maybe i wrong.
Thank you, Karthik

Comment: @zzfima. How about extending the factory interface with method like, GetAvailableSize(), which returns a list. Then on factory instance, check if a particular size is available, like if (instance.GetAvailableSize().Has(CarSize.BigCar)) { instance.CreateCar(CarSize.BigCar);}

Answer (score 0):

```
case CarSize.Big:
            car = new ThailandBigCar();
            break;
```

Try that. That should allow you to make big cars.

```
public interface ICar { }

public class USABigCar : ICar { }
public class USAMiddleCar : ICar { }
public class USALittleCar : ICar { }

public class ThailandMiddleCar : ICar { }
public class ThailandLittleCar : ICar { }
public class ThailandBigCar : ICar { }
```

Comment: Illuminati, in Thailand there is NO big cars. You can not just add it

Comment: Do you want to make big cars or not? You seem to contradict yourself about whether or not you want to be able to make big cars. Please tell me either, YES, I want to make big cars, or NO, I don't want to make big cars. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can not make big cars in Thailand. Once i could do it, but today Italian Hyper-Mega-Space forces destroed the factory. So, design changed and i can not do it. If i was can do it, i was not ask the question. The question is: what to do if design changed? And i try to find the answer